# How do you root the Samsung Galaxy Player?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-player

How can I root my Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0?

Comment: Have you ever rooted an android device before?

Comment: Rooting is not for everyone. You will be best off by waiting for the official update, which should come to your device before the end of the year. Just be sure to keep your data sync on- or otherwise check for system updates often.

Comment: For your second question please refer to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465) and the OS-upgrade one you linked, they're intended to be generic and cut off individual ROM questions.  If you have a specific problem while trying to flash a ROM you've found for your device, please do (separately) ask that sort of question!

Answer (score 3):

After enabling the `USB Debugging` option, [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/) can be used to root both Samsung Galaxy Player 4.0 and 5.0 handsets.  Download the latest version from [here](http://depositfiles.com/files/n0dcxce3t), and the walkthrough is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aA4bw8bU4T4).

In terms of updated OS versions, your best bet is custom ROMs that can be found on various forums like [XDA-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1423).

Comment: Chahk is right. Your best bet is CM10-

Answer (score 1):

This is going to take some work and some intense reading.

Check out this [XDA Dev forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1423)

The fastest way to root Samsung devices (IMHO) is [superoneclick](http://shortfuse.org/).